# Adding activity written in java to Android Phonegap application

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

My friend has a Phonegap application (written in JavaScript) that starts off with something similar to a gridview. I want to add a new item to this gridview and when the user clicks on it, I want to launch an Activity that I have written in java. Is this possible?

Best,

Aneem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a [plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) and use `this.ctx.startActivity(intent)` in the `execute()` method.